# how can I solve the following equation (without complex numbers)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$$
\sqrt{45-x^2} = 3- x^2
$$

$$
\sqrt{13-x^2} = 7 - x^2
$$

I have tried the Quadratic formula.  I always came up with the solution of $\{-3, 3\}$ by the first one and $\{-3, 3\}$ by the second one which is both wrong. Does this happen because I have to pay attention to a rule when substituting in a root, which I don't know, or how should I arrive at the solution that the first has none according to the graph and the second has the solution set according to the graph $\{-2,2\}$? I search a lot in the internet but there was no solution.

Comment: Can you show how you solved, for example the first one? Perhaps we can then see where the possible errors are, and point out how you can do it correctly.

Comment: To solve $\sqrt{a-x^2}=b-x^2$, call both expressions $y$ so $y^2=a-x^2=y+a-b$, so $y$ is a non-negative root of $t^2-t+b-a=0$. In both problems, there's exactly one such root because $b-a<0$. For your first problem, this implies $x^2<0$.

Comment: When I did the first one, I also got the answer $\{-3,3\}$ but then I realized that I had forgotten to note that both sides of the first equation have to be non-negative. The right-hand side then gives $3-x^2 \geq 0  \Rightarrow -\sqrt{3} \leq x \leq \sqrt{3}$. Contradiction. So this is an easy thing to forget.

Comment: It is not clear why you missed the solutions $-2$ and $2$ in the second problem.  Please edit your question to show how you arrived at your answers.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first equation:

A general strategy would be to square both sides:

$$\sqrt{45-x^2} = 3- x^2 \implies 45-x^2 = (3-x^2)^2 = 9+x^4-6x^2 \iff x^4-5x^2-36=0$$

Using $a=x^2$, the equation becomes $a^2-5a-36=0$ with $a\ge 0$. The Quadratic Formula indeed say that the solutions are $a=9$ and $a=-4$. Since $a\ge 0$, only $a=9$ is solution, so $x=\pm 3$.

But! **The first step of computation ($\sqrt{45-x^2}=3-x^2 \implies 45-x^2=(3-x^2)^2$) is an implication, not an equivalence**, so it is important to check that $3$ and $-3$ are indeed solution. As you check, they are not, so the equation has no real solution.

What are $3$ and $-3$ doing here? The equation $45-x^2=(3-x^2)^2$ is actually equivalent to $3-x^2=\pm\sqrt{45-x^2}$ (assuming $45-x^2\ge 0$). $4$ and $-3$ are solutions of the "twin" equation $3-x^2=-\sqrt{45-x^2}$.

---

Other method to see this equation has no solution: $3-x^2=\sqrt{45-x^2}$ implies that $3-x^2\ge 0$ so $x^2\le 3$, hence $3-x^2\le 3$. This in turn implies that $45-x^2\ge 42$ so $\sqrt{45-x^2}\ge\sqrt{42}>3\ge 3-x^2$ so the equation has no real solution.

Comment: You have a typographical error in the last line.  You meant to write $\sqrt{45 - x^2}$.  However, once you establish that $x^2 \leq 3$, you already know that there is no solution since $x^2 \geq 3 \implies -\sqrt{3} \leq x \leq \sqrt{3}$, but neither $-3$ nor $3$ is in the interval $[-\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: thanks! In the second method, I wanted to avoid solving the quadratic equation, so I couldn't use that $-3$ and $3$ are the only candidates to be solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Here my attempt,

$\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }=\mathrm{3}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $
$\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }=\left(\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} \right)−\mathrm{42} \\ $
$\left(\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }\right)^{\mathrm{2}} −\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }−\mathrm{42}=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\left(\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }+\mathrm{6}\right)\left(\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }−\mathrm{7}\right)=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\sqrt{\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }+\mathrm{6}=\mathrm{0}\Rightarrow{No}\:{Solution} \\ $
$\mathrm{45}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{7}^{\mathrm{2}} \Rightarrow{x}^{\mathrm{2}} =-\mathrm{4}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $
${x}=\pm\mathrm{2}{i}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $
$.\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $
$\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }=\mathrm{7}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $
$\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }=\left(\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} \right)−\mathrm{6} \\ $
$\left(\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }\right)^{\mathrm{2}} −\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }−\mathrm{6}=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\left(\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }+\mathrm{2}\right)\left(\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }−\mathrm{3}\right)=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\sqrt{\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} }+\mathrm{2}=\mathrm{0}\Rightarrow{No}\:{Solution} \\ $
$\mathrm{13}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{3}^{\mathrm{2}} \Rightarrow{x}^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{4}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $
${x}=\pm\mathrm{2} \\ $

Hope acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Define $u=3-x^2$. We have
$$\sqrt{42+u}=u$$
$$u^2=42+u$$
$$(u-7)(u+6)=0$$
$u=-6$ is extranneous. So $u=7$ is the only potential solution. This means that $x^2=-4$, which clearly has no real solutions.

For the other system, define $u=7-x^2$. We have
$$\sqrt{6+u}=u$$
$$u^2-u-6=0$$
$$(u-3)(u+2)=0$$
$u=-2$ is extranneous. So $u=3$ is the only potential solution. This means that $x^2=4$, so the only solutions are $x=\pm 2$.